# What does opt.apply_gradients() do in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

The documentation is not quite clear about this. I suppose the gradients one can obtain by `opt.compute_gradients(E, [v])` contain the `∂E/∂x = g(x)` for each element `x` of the tensor that `v` stores. Does `opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)` essentially execute `x ← -η·g(x)`, where `η` is the learning rate? That would imply that if I want to add a positive additive change `p` to the variable, I would need to need to change `g(x) ← g(x) - (1/η)p`, e.g. like this:

```py
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=l)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list)

for l, gv in enumerate(grads_and_vars):
    grads_and_vars[l] = (gv[0] - (1/l) * p, gv[1])

train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The update rule that the `apply_gradients` method actually applies depends on the specific optimizer. Take a look at the implementation of `apply_gradients` in the `tf.train.Optimizer` class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L257). It relies on the derived classes implementing the update rule in the methods `_apply_dense` and `_apply_spares`. The update rule you are referring to is implemented by the `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

Regarding your desired positive additive update: If what you are calling `opt` is an instantiation of `GradientDescentOptimizer`, then you could indeed achieve what you want to do by

```
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(E, [v])
eta = opt._learning_rate
my_grads_and_vars = [(g-(1/eta)*p, v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]
opt.apply_gradients(my_grads_and_vars)
```

The more elegant way to do this is probably to write a new optimizer (inheriting from `tf.train.Optimizer`) that implements your desired update rule directly.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the line ``opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=l)`` in the code snippet you provided, which makes the first paragraph of my answer somehow irrelevant. Leaving it in for context, nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks. Other gradient optimizer might calculate e.g. momenta based on my updated gradient, or why would they be incompatible with that approach?

Comment: Other optimizers implement update rules like gradient descent with momentum, AdaGrad, and so on. Of course, adding a constant value to the update step is compatible with any update rule (how sensible it is being a separate question).

Comment: What is p? Can you explain (g-(1/eta)*p, v)?

Comment: @Shaowu, see the question: `a positive additive change p`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use eager execution API.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
tfe = tf.contrib.eager
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
grad = tfe.implicit_gradients(loss)
optimizer.apply_gradients(grad(model_fn, val_list))
```

I will make an instance for it as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_exeuction()
tfe = tf.contrib.eager

W = tfe.Variable(np.random.randn())
b = tfe.Variable(np.random.randn())

def linear_regression(inputs):
    return inputs * W + b;

def MSE(model_fn, inputs, labels):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(model_fn(inputs) - labels, 2)) / (2 * n_samples)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
grad = tfe.implicit_gradients(MSE)
optimizer.apply_gradients(grad(linear_regression, train_X, train_Y)) # train_X and train_Y are your input data and label
```