# How to compute grads_and_vars with GradientDescentOptimizer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I have the following CNN code implementation.

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(cnn.learning_rate).minimize(loss = cnn.loss, global_step=global_step)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
```

Using it, I get the following error:

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'compute_gradients'
```

I noticed that using the above GradientDescentOptimizer implementation with tf.train.exponential_decay does not provide the attribute 'compute_gradients'
 for the optimizer.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients` are methods of the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` class.

The problem is that you are defining your optimizer as the step. You should remove the `minimize` call, like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(cnn.learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
```

and it should work.

However, if you are not doing any specific use of the gradients, you can indeed use `.minimize(...)` to directly define a training step, similarly to your `train_op`:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(cnn.learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=cnn.loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Further explanation on how `apply_gradients` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37922210/3991470).

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to look at the source code of optimizer.py in tensorflow (path: [/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py)) and you will get the answer.

The code snippet, i.e. from line 365 to line 423 is the implementation of `.minimize()` function. Don't worry, most of these are notes. In actually, it performs `.compute_gradients()` and `.apply_gradients()` together. So if you want to call `.compute_gradients()` alone, you have to ensure the variable is an instance of `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()`.