# Does tensorflow only optimize/update tf.get_variable and tf.Variable?

Tags: tensorflow, variables, optimization

Does TensorFlow only optimize `tf.Variable` and `tf.get_variable` tensors in the computational graph?

Comment: What else would it optimize?

Comment: I am new to tensorflow and trying to understand the computational graph a little better.  In order to compute the loss function that I am using, I need to perform some intermediate calculations and wanted to make sure it wouldn't try to optimize those.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more clear if you look at [what a TensorFlow `Optimizer` actually computes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37922210/6824418). There are two steps: it fetches gradients for variables, then it applies updates. So yes, only variables are optimized.